# How can I round a pandas Float64Index?

Tags: python, pandas

I've a `Float64Index` in pandas and would like to round it to 3 decimal points. There is no equivalent like `round()` for dataframes. How can I round a `Float64Index` to a specific floating point precision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`numpy.round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.round.html#numpy.ndarray.round):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),

}, index=[5.2563,3.25633,6.4538,9.236,2.236,4.2337])

df.index = np.round(df.index, 3)
print (df)
       A
5.256  a
3.256  b
6.454  c
9.236  d
2.236  e
4.234  f
```

Or convert index to `Series` and call [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
df.index = df.index.to_series().round(3)
```

Comment: The `to_series` is what I'm using right now. I thought probably there is a better workaround. Thx.